# Android Studio Kotlin - Onclick listener not being recognized

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, events, onclick

So this is my first time using Kotlin and Android studio and I really got to say thus far my experience has been horrible. No other language or IDE has put me in the position where I had to do more than hours research to try and make a simple button load the next page and then still being unable to do it.

[This is my Login.kt page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfWru.png)
and there you can see its having problems with the findviewbyID and setonlclicklistener.
[Top of my Activity_login.xml page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Q7c.png)
[The button im trying to create the onclick event for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VhfG.png)

Please keep in mind I did try just the normal creation of setonclick for the button but then I didnt seem to recognize that I have a button with the ID of login_btn

Comment: Any specific reason why you're importing `androidx.wear.tiles.material.Button` and not `android.widget.Button`?

Answer (score 0):

change the init button to

```
val button=findViewById<Button>(R.id.login_btn)
```

Comment: It has a problem with that too. Error being on the <Button> reason being: "Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'View!'"

Comment: if your view is button must cast <Button> or textview <TextView> and for other views same

Answer (score 0):

in my case i have removed onclick from xml.

```
val button : Button = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
    button.setOnClickListener { 
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If no answers above can help you, you can use viewbinding to access your view. I had so many problems while using findViewById as a newbie. Here is the documentation,

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding